# How to replace the words that appear once in a sentence in python

Tags: python

I want to replace the words that appear once in a sentence with `'<unk>'`. Like for a sentence: `hello hello world my world`, I want the output to be `hello hello world <unk> world`, how to do that?

Right now I'm doing like this:

```
 wordlist1 = trainfiles.split(None)
        wordlist2 = []
        for word1 in wordlist1:
            lastchar = word1[-1:]
            if lastchar in [",",".","!","?",";"]:
                word2 = word1.rstrip(lastchar)
            else:
                word2 = word1
            wordlist2.append(word2)
        freq = {}
        for word2 in wordlist2:
            freq[word2] = freq.get(word2,0)+1
        keylist = freq.keys()
        keylist.sort()

    for key2 in keylist:
        if freq[key2] == 1:
            print "%-10s %d" % ('<unk>', freq[key2])
        else:
            print "%-10s %d" % (key2, freq[key2])
```

Which gives me an output like:

```
hello   2
<unk>   1
world   2
```

But, I need the output like :

```
hello hello world <unk> world
```

How to do that?

Comment: concatenate the string and `print` it once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key, as @Cyber points out, it to use `collections.Counter`. This version preserves the original line's punctuation and whitespace.

```
import re
from collections import Counter
trainfiles = 'hello hello, world my world!'

wordlist = re.findall(r'\b\w+\b', trainfiles)
wordlist = Counter(wordlist)
for word, count in wordlist.items():
    if count == 1:
        trainfiles = re.sub(r'\b{}\b'.format(word), '<unk>', trainfiles)

print trainfiles
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `collections.Counter` to count the frequency the words in your sentence

```
from collections import Counter
s = 'hello hello world my world'
counts = Counter(s.split())
```

Then use a generator expression to replace any word that has a count of 1, and join the result a space character.

```
replaced = ' '.join(i if counts[i] > 1 else '<unk>' for i in s.split())
```

Result

```
'hello hello world <unk> world'
```

Comment: Why do I get an invalid syntax on collections in the import statement?

Comment: you should probably remove punctuation to get an accurate count `"hello hello.".split().count("hello") = 1`

Comment: It looks like the OP has already removed the punctuation by the time they get to the counting logic, but I could be mistaken.